# Как установить twilio на MacOS?

Tags: terminal, pip, install

Python: 3.6.3
pip: 9.0.1

[Инструкция Twilio по установке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQqDE.png)

**Способ 1**: не работает
а) запускаем terminal.app
б)

> $ pip install twilio Collecting twilio   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement twilio (from versions: )   No matching
>   distribution found for twilio

**Способ 2**: не работает
а) запускаем terminal.app
б)

```
$ curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python
-bash: $: command not found
```

**Способ 3**: не работает
а) запускаем terminal.app
б) скачиваем архив по [ссылке][2]
в) с помощью drag-n-drop тащим файл setup.py в terminal. Терминал прописывает путь.
г)

> /Volumes/D/Google\
>   Drive/ZUBER/Информационно-справочные/Обучение/Udacity\
>   (Python)/twilio-twilio-python-5f25b5b/setup.py python install from:
>   can't read /var/mail/**future**
>
> /Volumes/D/Google
>   Drive/ZUBER/Информационно-справочные/Обучение/Udacity
>   (Python)/twilio-twilio-python-5f25b5b/setup.py: line 2: import:
>   command not found from: can't read /var/mail/setuptools
>
> /Volumes/D/Google
>   Drive/ZUBER/Информационно-справочные/Обучение/Udacity
>   (Python)/twilio-twilio-python-5f25b5b/setup.py: line 5: **version**:
>   command not found
>
> /Volumes/D/Google
>   Drive/ZUBER/Информационно-справочные/Обучение/Udacity
>   (Python)/twilio-twilio-python-5f25b5b/setup.py: line 6: syntax error
>   near unexpected token `('
>
> /Volumes/D/Google
>   Drive/ZUBER/Информационно-справочные/Обучение/Udacity
>   (Python)/twilio-twilio-python-5f25b5b/setup.py: line 6: `with
>   open('twilio/**init**.py') as f:' Pushas-MacBook-Pro:~ puskarevaelena$

Что делать?
[image: способ 3 наглядно]

Answer (score 0):

Эта команда устанавливает **Twillio**

```
sudo pip install twilio --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudo c pip не следует использовать лучше :
python 2.7:

```
pip install twilio
```

python 3.x:

```
pip3 install twilio
```

зачем --upgrade ??? @Kosta B.